# Why's my icecream jelly like?

Tags: cream, ice-cream

I was following [this recipe](http://enthusiasts.ciachef.edu/ice-cream-with-whipped-cream/) to make some French Vanilla Icecream. I had to prepare some [home-made cream](http://www.wikihow.com/Make-Cream-from-Milk) from scratch, for I was very short on ingredients. After completing the cooking, during the freezing time, the mix became more jelly like - wobbly and rubbery. I kept stirring and breaking the mixture every 30 mins for the past 4 Hrs. I've followed the recipe as accurate as I could, but the home-made cream might be the trouble. Not only is it not setting, but is still in a runny consistency. Could it be the case? Is there anything that can be done right now?

Comment: I'll note that in addition to the much lower fat substitution SAJ14SAJ points out, you also substituted out an ice cream machine for some hand-stirring process. An ice cream machine is *much* more effective in making the small air bubbles you want in ice cream than hand stirring. There are ice cream recipes for if you don't have an ice cream machine, you should start with one of those.

Comment: Substitutions are only good for the context they are made for. You found a recipe with a substitute for whipped cream. In such situations, the probability that the recipe will also be good for other uses of cream is very low. Saj already answered the concrete question, but my general advice is to be very wary of substitutions and not to assume that they will behave similarly to the original in different conditions.

Comment: Probably because you added gelatin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ice cream depends critically on the fat in the dairy to form the structure and mouth feel.   Ice cream mixes there fore are typically fairly high in dairy fat.

You have substituted a comparatively low fat mock cream. which simply does not have the fat necessary to create the body of the ice cream.

In fact, the so-called homemade cream recipe is just thickening milk with gelatin, the thickening agent in... jelly (as they in British English, Jello in the US).  It is no wonder that your product has a jelly like consistency.   Also, gelatin is not stable for keeping its thickening (gelling) power when frozen.

Derobert is also correct in pointing out that switching from a traditional churned ice cream to a hand stirred freezer method will also alter the texture radically, although it is likely to make it grainier and icier without the milk fat to help buffer the formation of ice crystals.

Ice cream is a recipe where you do not want to substitute for the specific dairy called for in this way.  Ice milk recipes do exist, and will perform better.

Comment: Yeah, that "cream" recipe looks like it's meant for making a whipped cream substitute, definitely not the same role it's serving in ice cream.